# How to select the value in child form X when closing parent form Y?+1

Tags: c#

Here is the part of a custom winform class:

```
public partial class frmFindAppointments {
    public virtual void Init(int patientId, bool booleanValue) {
        // will receive the patientId
    }

    public delegate void goToCalendarHandler();
    public goToCalendarHandler goToCalendar;
}
```

In the parent window `y`, I added the name of an employer, and I want to get this selected in the child window `x` when I close the parent window `y`.

I tried with

```
using(frmFindAppointments frm=new frmFindAppointments()) {
    frm.goToCalendar+=new frmFindAppointments.goToCalendarHandler(GoToCalendar);
    frm.Init(Patient.Id, false);
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select the value in child form X when closing parent form Y?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220928/how-to-select-the-value-in-child-form-x-when-closing-parent-form-y)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is hard for me to understand your snippet of code.
But simple way of accomplishing that would be to create a SelectedEmployer property that you set to currently selected value on UI in Close handler of the y form. Then in X form, you can always retrieve this value even if the form y is closed, as long as you keep reference to y form. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create the child windows with some public properties you need to return as a result. Like:

```
public CForm : Form {
    public string Result { get; private set; } }
```

Then just set that property when you're done:

```
public CForm : Form {
    public void Finished() { Result = "all okay"; } }
```

Then just open is as dialog and get the result you need:

```
using (CForm form = new CForm)
{
    form.ShowDialog();
    string dialogResult = form.Result; // Here you are.
}
```